# Wen i delete my document from Firestore the corresponding image still remain in Storage

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am new in flutter, I am facing a problem which is how to delete Firestore photos.

I have created a Subcollection where I am storing my **products details**, this product also contains an **image** that is stored in Firebase Storage. If delete my product, like I have 10 products but I want to delete a specific product, when I am pressing the **delete button** it is deleting my products which is a **document** but it does not **delete the corresponding image** from Firebase Storage.

I have tried some way but it's not working, it's just deleting my **Cloud Firestore document** but the photo remains in Firebase Storage.

I am using the image URL to show the photo.  I want that when I click on my **delete** Button it also delete the corresponding image from Firebase Storage. so I am using this to delete my **Cloud Firestore** document.

```dart
TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(LoginUser!.uid)
        .collection('products')
        .doc(document.id)
        .delete()
        .then((value) async {
      //await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('productImage').child('productImageUrl').delete();
      
      
      print(
          'Product Deleted But image is still there in Storage Folder');
    });
  },
  child: Text('Delete')),
```

I am using This code to save my image Url in **Cloud Firestore**

```dart
final productImgRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('productImage')
    .child(FirebaseUser.uid +time +'.jpg');
await productImgRef.putFile(pickImageFile!);
var productImageUrl = await productImgRef.getDownloadURL();

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(FirebaseUser.uid)
    .collection('products')
    .add({
  'productName': _productName,
  'productDes': _productDes,
  'bidPrice': _bidPrice,
  'auctionDate': _auctionDate,
  'submitBy': userName,
  'productImageUrl': productImageUrl,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this commented out line is what you tried:

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('productImage').child('productImageUrl').delete();
```

The quotes around `'productImageUrl'` are a mistake there. With this code it tries to delete the image named `productImageUrl`, which is not what your image is called.

That the very least it should be:

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('productImage').child(productImageUrl).delete();
```

By removing the quotes from around `productImageUrl`, the code will use the **value** of the variable.

---

But more likely the `productImageUrl` contains a download URL, in which case your first need to map that back to a Storage `Reference` by calling the [`refFromURL`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/refFromURL.html) method:

```
var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(productImageUrl);
await storageRef.delete();
```